# necessary and sufficient condition on $(u_n)$ for a.s convergence of $\sum_n u_nX_n$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

I want to know if there is a necessary and sufficient condition on the sequence $(u_n)_n$ such that $\sum_n u_nX_n$ converges a.s. wehere $(X_n)_n$ are independent. 
I know that this series converges if and only if the three series of Kolmogorov converges, so can we **reduce** the conditions **only** on the sequence $(u_n)_n$ ? (for example if $\sum_n u_n$ is convergent...)

Comment: Do you want $(X_n)_n$ to be identically distributed...? If not, we cannot expect such a criterion; just choose $X_n := 1/u_n$ and the series will diverge... no matter how fast $u_n$ is decaying.

Comment: ok, let's suppose they are i.i.d

Comment: in these case is there a necessary and sufficient condition on $(u_n)_n$